# Visual Studio not finding reference in Class Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assemblies, using-statement

I'm building a class library with some utility functions that any of my projects can access. I need to be able to use some classes within the `System.Net` namespace, like `WebHeaderCollection`. Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't find them, and doesn't give me the option to resolve them by adding the correct using directive.

Not even after explicitly having added `System.Net` does it find the reference. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> I solved the problem. I had created a **Class Library (Package)** (used
>   for NuGet, where you edit the references in `project.json` instead of
>   going the `Add Reference...` route). This time I created a regular **Class Library** (in the Windows category) instead and references now work like a charm.

[image]

Comment: Have you added `System.Net.Requests` to the project references?

Comment: @Powerlord When I'm going to Add Reference... both 'Solution' and 'Assemblies' panes are empty for some reason. Is Class Library not allowed to use things from the framework?

Comment: @Powerlord Solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(v=vs.110).aspx).  That object is in the `System.Net.Requests` assembly:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting "The type or namespace name 'Requests' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: you'll need to add a reference to`System.Net.Requests`

Comment: Which I also did, but can you see the illogical error I'm getting?

Comment: you should just need to add a reference to `System.Net.Requests` in your project, and a `using` statement to `System.Net` and you'll be all set.  What's the issue?

Comment: VS is not recognizing this. Maybe it's because I created a Class Library (Package) instead of a normal Class Library? This one's maybe only to create NuGet packages, which is not my purpose. Let me try again